# Ruby Rails latst version not being used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing the Ruby on Rails 4 essential training with Kevin Skoglund. I installed Xcode and Homebrew no problems, was following along just fine when I went to do the command rbenv global 2.3.0 to change to the newest version, it won't do it. I was instructed to logout and back in, i shut down and restarted and I am still in version 2.0. How do I get it to change? I am a super noob, but I am brave. I would love to figure this out so i can get started.Also, i went to update my gems and this happened,

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
So I was stopped dead in my tracks, any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the case you missed a step on the `rbenv` installation. Unless the stub is installed in your `.bash_profile` (or equivalent), then `rbenv` won't engage on your shells properly.

Try repeating [step two on the Basic GitHub Checkout](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) step:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then check that it's installed correctly:

```
type rbenv
```

Which should be a function.

What you're describing is probably a `$PATH` issue where the system Ruby is taking priority. The `rbenv` one needs to come first.